# Form button not working properly in IE11(and probably more)

Tags: forms, button, explorer

I've made page where you can get an overview over invoices.
Everything works great, except from with Internet Explorer...
When I click the see order button, nothing happens in IE.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" onSubmit="window.location.reload()">
        <tr><td><?php
         $Date = $row['date'];
        echo $Date;
         ?></td><td><?php echo $row['autoid'];?></td>
        <input name='implodehideu' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $row['implodeuke'];?>;'>
        <input name='implodehidew' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $row['implodehelg'];?>;'>
        <input name='personid' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $row['primeid'];?>;'>
        <input name='invoiceid' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $row['autoid'];?>'>


        <td><input type="submit" name="seeorder" id="submit" value="Order overview"></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['surname'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['amount'];?></td>
        <?php
        if ($paidboolean)
            echo "<td bgcolor='#3AA849'>YES</td>";
        else
            echo "<td bgcolor='#e94336'>NO</td>";

        if (!$paidboolean) {
        ?>
        <td><input type="submit" name="confirm" id="submit" value="Mark as paid"></td>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
        <td><input type="submit" name="notconfirm" id="submit" value="Mark as not paid"></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <td><input type="submit" name="slett" id="submit" value="Slett"></td>
        </form>

   <?php
      if (isset($_POST['seeorder'])) {
          .....Things to show up
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the id argument of the submit button to something else than 'submit'. That helped me with the same problem.

```
<input type="submit" name="slett" id="btnSubmit" value="Slett" />
```